# Rounding a float to user-specified number of decimal places in C

Tags: c, floating-point, rounding

as in the question, how do I round the float to a user-specified number of decimal points? My current code only prints out the float to 2 decimal places. Also, is there a built-in function for such a purpose?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float x = 1.2345;
    int dp;
    printf("The float is: %f. How many decimal points to round to? ", x);
    scanf("%d", &dp);
    printf("Number: %.2f", x);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the `*` character in place of the precision, in which case the next argument will specify the precision.

```
printf("Number: %.*f", dp, x);
```

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: Closing just prevents new answers. Accepting and up-voting remain accessible.